# References on lattice-based cryptography

Tags: reference-request, lattice-crypto

I need earlier references (books, articles, etc) on lattice-based cryptography, and any advice will be helpful to me. I am reading Stinson & Paterson's [Cryptography: theory and practice](https://www.routledge.com/Cryptography-Theory-and-Practice/Stinson-Paterson/p/book/9781138197015). Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about telling us about your background, how much mathematics you know, etc. Otherwise any advice will be hard to give.

Comment: COMPLEX ITY OF
LATTICE PROBLEM S
A Cryptograp hic
Perspective
Daniele Micciancio
Shafi Goldwasser

Comment: You may want to take a look at Oded Regev's [lecture notes](https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2009) and at Chris Peikert's [lecture notes](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/lic13).

Comment: I have studied galois theory, nupber theory, elementary  optimization, numerical analysis, topology, integrations, differential geometry...@kelalaka thanks my mentor also gave it to me, thanks Mr kelalaka thanks Mr Rodrigo